# SQL Statement appears to work but doesnt display on website php SQL

Tags: php

hello im doing a website that sells games as a project and one of my problems is that i cant seem to display a value from the database on phpmyadmin onto the webpage, no errors are flagging up when i go on the page i want the value to be displayed so im presuming its working to some degree.

I have also entered the query into phpmyadmin to test it to see if there are any errors, but it displayed none and did the SELECT query just fine and outputted the desired result.

**Here is my query statement at the top of the page**

```
$query = "SELECT rectable.gameID, rectable.gameIMG, rectable.gamePrice, rectable.gameName, members.country, basket.quantity FROM rectable INNER JOIN basket 
ON rectable.gameID=basket.gameID INNER JOIN members ON basket.id=members.id
```

**It outputs the following**

[image: http://gyazo.com/1a33408ce0c2bf67a98c08f98624c539]

basically im trying to get the Country from the database and display it.

**My code within php is this**

```
<?php
$count = 0;
while ($count < $numrow)
{
$row = $results -> fetch_assoc();
extract($row);
echo"<div>";
echo"<div id='recommended_games2'>";
echo "<img src='images/".$gameIMG."' />";
echo "</div>";


echo '<div id="price_tag2">';
echo '<div class="price_tag" name="price" method="POST">£'.$gamePrice. '</div>';
echo'</div>';

echo '<div id="quantity_tag">';
echo '<div id="quantity_tag" >Quantity  '.$quantity.'</div>';
echo'</div>';

echo"<img class='box1' src='Images/Grey-Banners.png' />";
echo"</div>";
$count = $count + 1;  


}     
echo '<div id="delete_all">';
echo '<form action="cart.php">';
echo '<input id="hide_button" type="submit" value="Edit Cart"  />';
echo '</form>';
echo '</div>';

echo '<div id="totalprice">';
echo '<form action="" method="POST">';
echo '<input type="submit" value="Order Items"  />';
echo '</form>';
echo '</div>';

echo '<div id="address" >'.$country.'</div>';


?>
```

**It displays the website something like this**

[image: http://gyazo.com/75bafd47229f0521fb1868941e5f5f27]

But as you can see i cant get the country to be displayed.

Comment: You're out of loop scope.

Comment: ive tried putting it in the loop but it still doesnt display anything :/

Comment: You don't have any country assigned for the two items you've displayed in your screenshot.

Comment: Stick this --- echo '<div id="address" >'.$country.'</div>';  --- after the last div in ($quantity) --- any change?

Comment: so would i have to add the country field into the basket table from which these items are being displayed from?

Comment: Nope there was no change to my webpage

Answer (score 0):

try to change your loop like the following:

```
while ($row = $results -> fetch_assoc()) {
    echo"<div>";
    echo"<div id='recommended_games2'>";
    echo "<img src='images/".$row['gameIMG']."' />";
    echo "</div>";


    echo '<div id="price_tag2">';
    echo '<div class="price_tag" name="price" method="POST">£'.$row['gamePrice']. '</div>';
    echo'</div>';

    echo '<div id="quantity_tag">';
    echo '<div id="quantity_tag" >Quantity  '.$row['quantity'].'</div>';
    echo'</div>';

    echo"<img class='box1' src='Images/Grey-Banners.png' />";
    echo"</div>";
    echo '<div id="address" >'.$row['country'].'</div>';
}
```

Comment: i have just changed it to this but i still get the same outcome as displayed in my screenshot, it just doesnt display the country

Comment: you can do `var_dump($row)` see the values of this object

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure here, but you have "INNER JOIN members ON basket.**id**=members.id" in your code while you joined basket on rectable with gameID. Do you have two different ID columns in your "basket" table?

Comment: basically i recently decided to have this address thingy part of my page so initially i had a basket table with only the fields: orderID
gameID
id
orderdate 
quantity

Comment: What does your DB schema for these tables look like?

Comment: How do i check this for my current tables because this is where i really flopped because i did this website and database without drawing it out first but went from the top of my head :/

Comment: Well, basically, what are the fields in your tables? If you use PHP my admin, simply clicking on the table name will give you this, or if you use command line use "describe basket", etc.

Comment: ITS all good now i have solved the problem which i will post in 8 hours since im fairly new :P, but basically it was working however because ive set session and id variable somewhere in log in page and checkout page it meant the order page was unique to that user and becaus ei was logged in as 'Gavin' which didnt have a country set it displayed nothing -.-. So logging in as Admin  meant it displayed the country  for the obvious reason i entered a country only for that user..... Thank you so much all for the help appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for you help but i have realised the problem which i think brian driscoll sort of answered, Basically it was basically working but the reason for it not displaying is because in my database i only entered the address for one of the users and for it to be displayed you had to be logged on as that user, since i have set up session variables and ids which meant each cart was specific to the user. Which meant only the country that was associated with the user was displayed.

Thanks for the help guys